# personalizar el cuadro de dialogo de inicio de sesión en facebook

Tags: javascript, api, facebook

Tengo creada una aplicación en facebook, uso el SDK para el inicio de sesión. funciona bien, pero  le ocurre lo siguiente:
1.- Si ya tengo iniciada la sesión en facebook, inicia automáticamente la sesión en mi aplicación (sitio web), en otros sitios he visto que cuando ya tengo iniciada mi sesión en facebook y quiero comentar en el sitio, me muestra otro cuadro de dialogo con mis datos y me pide autorización para acceder. en mi sitio no lo hace así, simplemente se logea y ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy probable que en esos sitios el token de acceso del usuario no es almacenado o el tiempo de vida del token no es extendido (el token de acceso tiene una vida de unas cuantas horas), por lo tanto, cuando intentas acceder el token a vencido y es necesario solicitar un nuevo token de acceso de usuario (ventana de autorizacion).

[Facebook: Tiempo de vida de un token de acceso](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension)

[Facebook: Tipos de tokens de acceso](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)